# ng-model not change after save editing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

i try to make simple CRUD with angularjs and php api
the problem is in angularjs

i have code like this :

```
    $scope.editData = function(pid) {
    $scope.hideform = false;

    $scope.edit = false;
    $scope.pid = $scope.projects[pid].pid;
    $scope.title = $scope.projects[pid].title;
    $scope.pcode = $scope.projects[pid].pcode;
    $scope.type = $scope.projects[pid].type;
    $scope.proj_type = $scope.projects[pid].proj_type;
    };
$scope.saveData = function(pid, title, pcode, type2, proj_type){
        $http.post("api/getProject.php",
            {type: "edit", id:pid, title:title, pcode:pcode, type2:type2, proj_type:proj_type})
            .success(function(data) {
                notification(data.success, data.message);
                $scope.hideform = true;
        });
    };
```

and have form for editing data (edit button clicked , then show form edit with ng-model loaded on it

like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-hide="hideform" ng-submit="saveData(pid,title, pcode, type, proj_type)">

<h3 ng-hide="edit">Edit Project:</h3>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">PID:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" ng-model="pid" ng-disabled="!edit" placeholder="PID">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" ng-model="title" placeholder="Title">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pcode:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" ng-model="pcode" placeholder="Pcode">
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="error || incomplete">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save Changes
</button>
</form>
```

the script are working , but everytime i click save editing then click edit button (on each row on table) , the ng-model on form input still same like the last data what i save but other input are changed , ex : i edited title , when click edit button on different row on the table , just pcode changed to different row data , the Title still same like the last data i edit
sorry if my explanation make all of you confuse
Any help will be appreciated

here is the image if my explanation not clear
[image: Image for explanation]

Comment: i dont understand your question properly. Is "Save Changes" working correctly? Also you have to update your projects array in angular after saving data

Comment: Save Changes is working correctly but ng-model not refreshing 
as you can see on the picture , Title not changing after i save changes TestingBABIBUS then click Edit on Testing3 row :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem resolved using

```
$scope.selectedProject = $scope.projects[pid];
```

so editData function look like this

```
$scope.editData = function(pid) {

        $scope.hideform = false;

        $scope.edit = false;
        $scope.pid = $scope.projects[pid].pid;
        $scope.title = $scope.projects[pid].title;
        $scope.pcode = $scope.projects[pid].pcode;
        $scope.type = $scope.projects[pid].type;
        $scope.proj_type = $scope.projects[pid].proj_type;

        $scope.selectedProject = $scope.projects[pid];
    };
```

and ng-model (on every input)
need to change like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedProject.pid" ng-disabled="!edit" placeholder="PID">
```

instead of this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="pid" ng-disabled="!edit" placeholder="PID">
```

Now every ng-model changed every edit button has been click after save Changes button clicked :)
Thank you!